# Execute task in background

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my app after user press start button I execute some code in `for` cycle. 
How to keep application responsible for user interaction during this?
In C# there is BackgroundWorker class, is there anything similar in IOS?

Comment: Take a look at [dispatch queues](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selector like this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(yourForCycle:) withObject:nil];


-(void)yourForCycle:(id)sender {

    //Your for cycle...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use gcd like following

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^  {  
   //Put your heavy code here it will not block the user interface
});
```